# Firestore realtime listeners when your web app is in the background

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

the code below adds a listener to a firestore collection and sends a push notification when the web app is in the foreground. Is it possible to do the same in the background, perhaps, via service worker? 
I tried to import the firebase module to the service worker but I did not succeed

```
db.collection("favorites").onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        var response =snapshot.docChanges();
        response.forEach(function(change) {
                if (change.type === "added") {
                    var bodyPaint="New favorites: ";
                }
                if (change.type === "modified") {
                    var bodyPaint="Modified favorites: "; 
                }
                if (change.type === "removed") {
                    var bodyPaint="Removed favorites: ";
                }

            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
                const title = 'LA BUENOS AIRES';
                const options = {
                  body: bodyPaint,
                  icon: 'images/icon.png',
                  badge: 'images/badge.png'
                };
                registration.showNotification(title, options);
              });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service worker cannot maintain a persistent connection to a server like that.

You can run a [Cloud Function trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that listens for the changes and when something needs a notification to the user, you can send a [push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

Comment: thanks for the links Abraham, me imaginaba que tendría que hacerlo con firebase functions